# How to disable access to certain parts of an express server but be able to enable it later

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a server that is fully functioning, but I only want it to be accessable when I say. I do this via a discord bot which works fine. I currently have a boolean variable `server_on` and an 
 `if (server on) { do }` 
in all of my `app.get` and `app.post` functions. 
Is there a  cleaner way to do this, or is this if statement in every function the only way?

Edit:
Final working code

```
var block_server_middleware = function (req, res, next) {
    if (!server_on) { res.send("server is currently unavailable") }
    else { next() }
}

app.use(block_server_middleware)
```

and the other `app.get` and `app.post` functions were not changed at all
This was the only few lines added that made the whole idea work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define one middleware function that goes before all your routes are defined:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!server_on) {
        // stop all routing
        res.send("server not on!");
    } else {
        // let routing continue
        next();
    }
});
```

This will keep your routes from ever getting run until `server_on` is back to true.  If you have any routes you want to leave open all the time, then just place them before this middleware.

You can replace `res.send("server not on!");` with whatever is appropriate for your use.  You can return a single web page or you can send back a 4xx or 5xx error status (perhaps a 503 error).

Comment: What exactly do I put in place of `next();`?
i've tried putting my `app.get` statements there and the if statemnets are working ok as my `console.log` outputs correctly

Comment: with `res.send` it says res is not defined so i'm not really sure what to do

Comment: Ok with a little bit of research I figured it out. Added `(req, res, next)` to the app.use function and now it works as intended. Thank you for letting me know what I wanted was called middleware, helped the research efforts a lot!

Comment: @Mathias - Yeah, sorry I accidentally left out the `(req, res, next)` part.  I corrected the answer.  Glad you figured it out.

Comment: No problem. It will probably stick in my head for longer